# Phone number validation using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, html, jsp

I am new to Java and Regex.

I have to do simple phone number validations.

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10">
```

Here user can't entered more than 10 characters. but i need, if user try to enter string values should not allow. Only numbers should allow.and no space in between numbers also should not allow. Please help me how can achieve with reqex.

Comment: `<input type="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}">`. Or do you want to disallow entering non-digits from keyboard?

Comment: yes, i want to disallow to enter non digits from keyboard.

Comment: Try `<input onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="number" maxlength="10" />` - not sure what type you need, try with `type="number"` and `type="tel"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:- awesome. It works. Thank you.  Here, what is 57 , 48 ? is this code for keyboard strings ?

Comment: Yes, these are decimal values of digits. The initial check for 8 and 0 codes will handle backspace key correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<input onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="number" maxlength="10" />
```

- `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"` will handle numeric input
- `maxlength="10"` - will set the max symbol length.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<input type="number" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" />
```

Comment: But we have to restrict to user not to enter String. maxLength="10" is working perfectly for length.

Comment: here it can not allow to enter string also..it is just allowed to enter only numbers

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="number" maxlength="10">
```